# Sending bz2-compressed data as utf-8 string via gunicorn with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, gunicorn

I am trying to use gunicorn to send a utf-8 encoded string, which is the result a bz2 compression, as the response to a get request.

Here is my code on gunicorn server side:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    data = "Hello, World!" * 10
    compressed_data = bz2.compress(data)
    start_response("200 OK", [("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
                              ('charset', 'utf-8'),
                              ("Content-Length", str(len(compressed_data))),
                              ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'),
                              ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'),
                              # ('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'BASE64'),
                          ])
    return iter([compressed_data])
```

and when I try to get the request from client side using Python requests package like this

```
import bz2
import requests
res = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
bz2.decompress(res.text)
```

it is raising an exception

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xab' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

saying the response cant not be decoded
when trying to print the text of response

```
print(res.text)
>>u'BZh91AY&SYy\xabm\x99\x00\x00\x13\x97\x80`\x04\x00@\x00\x80\x06\x04\x90\x00 \x00\xa5P\xd0\xda\x10\x03\x0e\xd3\xd4\xdai4\x9bO\x93\x13\x13\xc2b~\x9c\x17rE8P\x90y\xabm\x99'
```

when printing the encoded text

```
import bz2
print(bz2.compress("Hello, World!" * 10))
>> 'BZh91AY&SYy\xabm\x99\x00\x00\x13\x97\x80`\x04\x00@\x00\x80\x06\x04\x90\x00 \x00\xa5P\xd0\xda\x10\x03\x0e\xd3\xd4\xdai4\x9bO\x93\x13\x13\xc2b~\x9c\x17rE8P\x90y\xabm\x99'
```

the only difference is the unicode sign, I am solving this issue by tweaking the data on the client side to make the response string decodeable, but I am wondering how I can solve this problem on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send bzip2 compressed data as utf-8. It is binary data, it is not text.

If your http client accepts bzip2 content-encoding ([`bzip2` is not standard](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters/http-parameters.xhtml#content-coding)) then you could sent a utf-8 encoded text compressed using bzip2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import bz2

def app(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')]
    data = (u'Hello \N{SNOWMAN}\n' * 10).encode('utf-8')

    if 'bzip2' in environ.get('HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING', ''): # use bzip2 only if requested
        data = bz2.compress(data)
        headers.append(('Content-Encoding', 'bzip2'))

    headers.append(('Content-Length', str(len(data))))
    start_response(status, headers)
    return data
```

#### Example

Uncompressed response:

```
$ http -v 127.0.0.1:8000
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.2



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 100
Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 17 May 2015 18:47:50 GMT
Server: gunicorn/19.3.0

Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
```

bzip2 compressed response if the client specifies that it accepts bzip2:

```
$ http -v 127.0.0.1:8000 Accept-Encoding:bzip2 
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: bzip2
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.2



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Encoding: bzip2
Content-Length: 65
Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 17 May 2015 18:48:23 GMT
Server: gunicorn/19.3.0



+-----------------------------------------+
| NOTE: binary data not shown in terminal |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Here's corresponding http client that uses `requests` library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import bz2
import requests # $ pip install requests

r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000', headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, bzip2'})
content = r.content
print(len(content))
if r.headers['Content-Encoding'].endswith('bzip2'): # requests doesn't understand bzip2
    content = bz2.decompress(content)
print(len(content))
text = content.decode(r.encoding)
print(len(text))
print(text, end='')
```

#### Output

```
65
100
80
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
```

---

Otherwise (no non-standard accept-encoding), you should send your data as `application/octet-stream` as [@icedtrees suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30253928/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import bz2

def app(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    headers = [('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream')]
    data = bz2.compress((u'Hello \N{SNOWMAN}\n' * 10).encode('utf-8'))

    headers.append(('Content-Length', str(len(data))))
    start_response(status, headers)
    return data
```

#### Example

```
$ http 127.0.0.1:8000 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 65
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Date: Sun, 17 May 2015 18:53:55 GMT
Server: gunicorn/19.3.0



+-----------------------------------------+
| NOTE: binary data not shown in terminal |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

`bzcat` accepts bzip2 content:

```
$ http 127.0.0.1:8000 | bzcat
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
Hello ☃
```

The data is shown correctly because the terminal uses utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the string comes in as unicode. You should not be trying to interpret bz2 compressed data as text.

See [request docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) on how to interpret the data as raw data rather than text:

```
res.content  # not res.text
```

Additionally, the data should not be sent as `text/plain` in the first place. BZ2 compressed data is not text, and should be sent as `application/octet-stream` (i.e. byte stream).

Quick hack to reinterpret text as byte stream (since the default ascii codec will not cope with bytes out of the range 0-127, we use `ISO-8859-1` to encode the data.

```
>>> text = u'BZh91AY&SYy\xabm\x99\x00\x00\x13\x97\x80`\x04\x00@\x00\x80\x06\x04\x90\x00 \x00 \xa5P\xd0\xda\x10\x03\x0e\xd3\xd4\xdai4\x9bO\x93\x13\x13\xc2b~\x9c\x17rE8P\x90y\xabm\x99'
>>> byte_string = text.encode('ISO-8859-1')
>>> byte_string
'BZh91AY&SYy\xabm\x99\x00\x00\x13\x97\x80`\x04\x00@\x00\x80\x06\x04\x90\x00 \x00 \xa5P\xd0\xda\x10\x03\x0e\xd3\xd4\xdai4\x9bO\x93\x13\x13\xc2b~\x9c\x17rE8P\x90y\xabm\x99'
>>> bz2.decompress(byte_string)
'Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!'
```

But ideally you should fix your data type.